# Saving XLSB with structure protection, creates encrypted file format

Tags: .net, aspose, aspose-cells

So I’m loading a XLSB file into a workbook using Apose.cells (21.5.0) then saving it out. The issue I’m having is that the produced file will out open, when the original file opens just fine. Below is a walkthrough of what I have found.

Code being used. I simplified it to ensure nothing else was introducing the error.

```
var wb = new Workbook("FilewithPwProtectedStructure.xlsb");
wb.Save("FilewithPwProtectedStructureSavedFromAspose.xlsb", SaveFormat.Xlsb);
```

This file has the protection level of “structure”, and is protected is a password.

When opening the original file as an archive, we get the following.

[InternalFileStructureOfOriginalFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpEp1.png)

This file opens without issue, and the structure is password protected. But once this file is opened then saved again by Aspose we get the following when opened as an archive.

[InternalFileStructurePostAsposeSave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ8E7.png)

As we can see aspose saved the file out in an encrypted format.

I would like to know if this is expected behavior, and if so how could I configure Aspose to export the file in a way that will preserve the original files internal structure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose has fixed this issue in their latest fix. v21.5.6

Comment: Yes, we fixed similar issue (regarding protection) in the new version v21.6, so it's  worth trying it.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.